# Evaluate $\int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} f(z) dz$ for some meromorphic $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

This is for homework, so just hints please!  The question asks

> If $f$ is a meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $|f(z) z^2| \leq 1$ for $|z| \geq 1$, then evaluate $\int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} f(z) dz$ (where $\mathbf{D}$ represents the unit disk).

Since $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, it is certainly meromorphic on $\mathbf{D}$.  This means that there are at most finitely many poles $\{ z_0, \dotsc, z_n \}$ of $f$ in $\mathbf{D}$.  By the residue theorem, then,
$$ \int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} f(z) dz = \sum_{i=0}^n \text{Res}_{z = z_i} \left[ f(z) \right]. $$
However, by the condition $|f(z) z^2| \leq 1$ for $|z| \geq 1$, we see that the Laurent series of $f$ about each $z_i$ contains no powers greater than $-2$.  For example, $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^3}$ does not fit our criterion.  The residue of $f$ at a point is defined to be the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f$.  Thus, $\text{Res}_{z = z_i} \left[ f(z) \right] = 0$ for every $i$, and hence
$$ \int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} f(z) dz = 0. $$

Does this look OK?  I have a feeling that there is a mistake somewhere but am not sure where.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I agree.  Looks good.

Comment: Looks good. Alternative proof to check your argument: Deform the integration path from $\partial D$ to the boundary of a really large circle and estimate the integral.

Comment: Can you perhaps be more explicit about how you are reaching the conclusion that the Laurent coefficients must be zero for $n > -2$?

Comment: @EricAuld  If a coefficient of the Laurent series of $f$ is nonzero for $n > 2$, then $|f(z) z^2| \nleq 1$ for $|z| \geq 1$, right?

Comment: @tylerc0816 That sounds right, but I am trying to justify that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end result is correct. However, the way to it isn't.

> Thus, $\text{Res}_{z = z_i} \left[ f(z) \right] = 0$ for every $i$

is wrong. Consider for example

$$f(z) = \frac12\left(\frac{1}{z-\frac12} - \frac{1}{z+\frac12}\right) = \frac{1}{2(z^2-\frac14)}.$$

That satisfies the criterion $\lvert f(z)z^2\rvert \leqslant 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 1$, but it has two poles with nonzero residue.

The condition $\lvert f(z)z^2 \rvert \leqslant 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 1$ ensures that $f$ has a zero of order (at least) $2$ in $\infty$. Thus $f$ is a rational function, and the sum of all residues of a rational function is $0$. The fact that $f$ has a multiple zero in $\infty$ means that the residue in $\infty$ is $0$, hence the sum of all residues in $\mathbb{C}$ (which is the sum of the residues in $\mathbb{D}$) is $0$.

Comment: More specifically, the sum of the residues of a rational function $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ -- such that $\deg p(z) < \deg q(z) - 1$ (which is what we have) -- is 0, correct?

Comment: Any rational function, but you must include the residue in $\infty$.

Comment: Why is the sum of all residues of a rational function equal to zero? If it is lengthy to explain, do you know a reference? Thanks

Comment: @EricAuld The short reason is that the sum of residues of a meromorphic function on a compact Riemann surface is $0$, and a rational function is a meromorphic function on the compact Riemann surface $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$. One can of course prove that special case with more elementary means, but I'll have to think about it, need to fully wake up first.

Comment: @DanielFischer Did you ever get a chance to think about this one? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, @EricAuld, completely forgot about it. Let me think for a moment, I'm not three quarters asleep now.

Comment: @EricAuld Make a partial fraction decomposition of the rational function, $$R(z)=P(z)+\sum_{k=1}^p h_k(z),$$ where $h_k(z)$ is the principal part of the Laurent series in the pole $a_k$. The residue of $f$ in $\infty$, where $f$ is holomorphic in a punctured neighbourhood of $\infty$ is the residue of $-\frac{1}{w^2}\cdot f\left(\frac1w\right)$ in $0$. $P(z)$ has residue $0$ (since $a_k z^k \leadsto -a_k w^{-(k+2)}$). The residue of $\dfrac{1}{(z-a)^n}$ in $\infty$ is $$\operatorname{Res}\left(-\frac{1}{w^2} \frac{1}{\left(\frac1w-a\right)^n} ;0\right),$$ and expanding the second into a Taylor

Comment: series produces $w^n + anw^{n+1} + \dotsb$, so the only term that produces a residue is for $n = 1$, and its residue in $\infty$ is $-1$, while its residue in $a$ is $+1$. So every principal part produces a total residue of $0$, and thus the sum of all residues is $0$.